# Why action bar Back button design is broken

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to Android. This activity is parent activity of MainActivity. I add below line on this activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

But back button design happened like that

[image]

This activiy desing like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_detail_movie"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.emrekose.cinefily.ui.activity.DetailMovieActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_header_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#99000026"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_movie_poster"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/no_movie_image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_original_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_genres"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I can't solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

change this line value to your height.